# Spam prevention (rate limiting)

Tags: limit, spam, rate

To sign up, the end user submits an email form, only email form, after which they receive an "activation" link which points them to an form where they can fill in the password and full name.

I do this to prevent fake accounts, the only problem is, what if a hacker creates a script that POST the email form 1.000.000 times and proxies the IP address of each request.

Since hackers can use proxies, IP based rate limiting would not be an option, they can jump proxies.

My application uses Amazon SES (costs me $1 for 10.000 emails, so 1.000.000 POSTS to my email form, would give me a bill of $100)

I have been thinking about setting up a custom SMTP server, so I prevent the billing, but still how can I prevent this? I don't want to use captcha when users sign up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be captcha - sometimes even image-text that some captcha systems produce can be read by bots or proxies - you can use some human based question, like simple mathematical terms, or question about capitals of several famous countries.
also you can use this method as an intermediate page that if answered correctly it takes the user to the form page.

Comment: hackers can bypass questions easily, they can loop through all possible questions, then parse it and they know the answer. Email verification to me seems the only way to actually prevent fake accounts and spammers, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: you need to provide more than several question though, and you write them randomly every time the page is launched, email verification is good but the hacker can use it like any other "good" guy just to get the form where they can fill in the password and full name and after that he uses his proxies, use both techniques in mixed

Comment: I just really don't want any captcha or any question, its very anoying and I don't see that big boys like facebook, twitter etc are using such a technique, however they do some IP based rate limiting, and that leads me to my next question, is IP based rate limiting good enough, I mean, I know that hackers can proxy to get another IP but can they do this quickly, and inifinite times? Another technique might be to check what the time is between sign up and the "user" clicking the activation link, if it is too fast, we got a hacker (under 500ms or so)

Comment: please take a look at this: http://hastebin.com/gamanobowa.coffee wouldn't this be a solid solution? (if ofcourse lots of random questions exist)

Comment: yeah something like that, just don't rely totally on numeric answers, use some question that require text also, and you may use some randomly auto-generated PIN code sent to the verification email that contains the activation and demand them to write it into its field in the registration form. big guys you mentioned (twitter) have been attacked too.